# member not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in mapping

Tags: solidity, addresses, mapping, memory, calldata

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.7.0;

contract New{

    mapping(address => string) public users;

    string name;

    address[] public userAddress ;
    //string[] public userNames;

    function updateUser(string memory name) public{
        users[msg.sender]= name;

    }
    function getUser(address[] calldata) external view returns(string memory){
        return users.name;
    }

}
```

I want to set a name and I want to get my name.For this reason I made a getUser func. but I can't get my name.

but I have got a error like this :

```
browser/asd.sol:17:16: TypeError: Member "name" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in mapping(address => string storage ref). return users.name; ^--------^
```

what should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.7.0;

contract New{

    mapping(address => string) public users; // contains a name for every address

    // string name;

    // address[] public userAddress ;
    // string[] public userNames;

    function updateUser(string memory name) public {
        users[msg.sender] = name; // set name for address

    }
    function getUser(address a) public view returns(string memory) {
        return users[a]; // return address name
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.